# Duplicates data on mysql single insert query

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, mariadb

I've created a userlog table

timestamp datetime(3) 
event   char(25)

```
vartimestamp =date('Y-m-d H:i:s'). substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8);;
$varevent="loginattempt";
$stmt = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO userlog(timestamp, event) VALUES('$vartimestamp', '$varevent')");

if($stmt->execute())
echo "Successful";
else    echo "Error";
```

and i get success result.
But the records are duplicated

1st Attempt

```
2017-04-04 14:59:02.007   loginattempt
2017-04-04 14:59:02.025   loginattempt
```

2nd Attempt

```
2017-04-04 15:00:30.200   loginattempt
2017-04-04 15:00:30.218   loginattempt
```

How to avoid duplication while using the datetime(3)  column with index

Comment: The timestamp isn't duplicate as you can see, each entry have a different time, for the "event", then you've written your `$varevent` to have a static value, why do you expect it to change?

Comment: No the problem is when the query is called it duplicates the records.(Ex. 2017-04-04 14:59:02.007  and 2017-04-04 14:59:02.025 are single query execution. I thought it was a problem due to datetime(3) because datetime(0) doesn't show duplicated results.

Comment: This is not the way to use prepared statements

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I tried stmt->bindParam(":etimestamp", $vartimestamp) too. same results.

Comment: Hmmm... 18ms?  I'll bet you are on Windows with a crummy implementation of millisecconds?

Comment: Try `datetime(0)` a couple dozen times -- I'll bet you will get it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You are working too hard - skip the PHP code, and note that you can do the work in MySQL:

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(3);
+-------------------------+
| NOW(3)                  |
+-------------------------+
| 2017-04-04 10:13:06.862 |
+-------------------------+
```

So, use `INSERT ... VALUES (NOW(3), ...`

Don't use `CHAR` unless the strings are really fixed width; use `VARCHAR`.

Back to the *real* bug in the code.  Each invocation of a PHP script from a browser leads to starting over -- so you are destined to get a new datetime, wither you do it in PHP code or MySQL code.  Rethink your design.

If, on the other hand, you are saying that `execute()` is being performed twice, then I don't see it in the limited code segment you provided.

I would *guess* that the package that provides `$DBcon` is doing something naughty; dig into it.